# How can I set a default image file in file_field_tag on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a rails form to load an image

```
<%= file_field_tag :photo, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif' %>
```

How can I set a default image when the user is not load one.

Comment: have you tried this e.g. `file_field_tag 'resume', value: '~/resume.doc'`

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to set a default in the model. That way, the default is only uploaded once rather than for every time the form is field in without an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set default value for input type="file"

Answer (score -2):

the best way you need to do is on your view

```
<td><img src="/assets/thumb_default.png" alt="Thumb default" /></td>
```

after src your default image src and specify a name if image is available..

Comment: OP was talking about the `file_field` helper in Rails. This answer has nothing to do with the original question.